Connect Macbook (M2) to SQL Server 2016 via ODBC
I am trying to query a SQL Server 2016 database via a jupyter notebook in VSCode. To do this, I've followed these instructions to install the ODBC drivers.
This is the output of the odbcinst -j command:
unixODBC 2.3.12
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/myname/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

Then I run the following python code in VSCode:
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

servername = 'emp-edwh01'
dbname = 'DWH_CORE'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+servername+';DATABASE='+dbname)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query = '''SELECT * limit 100
                 FROM dbp.tab_CMA_CMPositions
        '''

df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, index_col='[primary_key]')

but the output I see is:
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have done thorough research (went through this, too), deleted and re-installed drivers, double checked all links, etc. But still I can't connect.
In addition, the full log of when I run the connection file on VSCode is:
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.229336][SQLAllocHandle.c][469]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x7fdf0b3a6400
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.229385][SQLAllocHandle.c][585]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x7fdeeb188e00
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.230136][SQLDriverConnectW.c][298]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fdeeb188e00
            Window Hdl = 0x0
            Str In = [DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=emp-edwh01;DATABASE=DWH_CORE][length = 74 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x0
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = 0x0
            Completion = 0
        Threading Level set from Driver Entry in ODBCINST.INI 99 from '99'

        Threading Level set from [ODBC] Section in ODBCINST.INI 0 from '0'

        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UCS-2-INTERNAL'

[ODBC][13195][1728651033.367613][SQLDriverConnectW.c][870]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.367677][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][535]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fdeeb188e00
            Rec Number = 1
            SQLState = 0x30a3f4824
            Native = 0x30a3f4818
            Message Text = 0x7fdf0c5f2e00
            Buffer Length = 1023
            Text Len Ptr = 0x30a3f4822
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.367732][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][596]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            SQLState = [08001]
            Native = 0x30a3f4818 -> 0 (32 bits)
            Message Text = [[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see]
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.367851][SQLFreeHandle.c][324]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x7fdeeb188e00
[ODBC][13195][1728651033.367882][SQLFreeHandle.c][373]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]

EDIT - CERTIFICATES
I use Kerberos to authenticate and connect. And this works successfully through Kerberos when I query directly the same SQL Server 2016 in VSCode.
I've tried running the python script to trust the server certificates:
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+servername+';DATABASE='+dbname+';TrustServerCertificate=yes')

Now the error I see is:
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')


I assume that you have therefore confirmed that it's not a certificate error and followed the guidance in the linked page? You don't mention certificates once above, so can you [edit] your question to advise what you tried in regards to that?

Also, as you don't supply a user name or password, I assume that kerboros is configured on your Apple device, and it's connected to the same domain that the SQL Server is in?

"EDIT - CERTIFICATES" What about them...? "CERTIFICATES" tells us nothing.

@ThomA, I need your guidance here as I am not an expert of the matter. Can you be more specific on which information I should provide to get your help?

The documentation you are linked to in the error gives you the information; I'm asking about what actions you did that that documentation tells you to do.

@ThomA the documentation linked in the error mentions 2 types of certificates errors. I don't see either of these 2 error types in any of the output. However, I tried trusting the certificates (see update in the edit) and I have a new error.

Solved by following these steps.
To the python query, I've added TrustServerCertificate=yes and  Trusted_connection=yes: the first one to trust the certificates from the server; the second one to authenticate via the Windows login/password, without giving them as input in the code.
The final connection string is now:
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+servername+';DATABASE='+dbname+ \
                      ';TrustServerCertificate=yes; Trusted_connection=yes')

After this, I have made sure to use the right OpenSSL library version. As I have read that the ODBC driver does not support OpenSSL3, I've switched back to OpenSSL1 and I fixed all links.
It didn't work straight after this step, but a reboot was required.
